# maximum recursion deep exceeded when calling for an object attribute

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and I have decided to create a module to manage my monthly budget as a learning occasion.
The basic object in the module would be Debit, defined as

```
class Debit(object):

    currency = "SEK"

    def __init__(self,date,tag,ammount):
        self.date = date
        self.tag = tag
        self.ammount = ammount
```

I wanted to be able to control that the attribute of this object are entered correctly, and to do so I tried to play with the properties like this

```
@property
def date(self):
    return self.date
@date.setter
def date(self, d):
    if len(d) == 0: 
        raise Exception("Date cannot be empty")
        self.date = d
```

NB: the condition and the exception in the date.setter will be changed into something more relevant, I just wanted to try an exception
This works only half way: indeed, if I try to enter an empty string for date, I got the exception raised. However, when I enter a correct date and then I tried to retrieve using .date I got the following error

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I suppose that I am doing something bad when naming "date" inside the properties and the setter, forcing python into an infinite loop, but I can not really get my head around it.

Any help ?

Comment: date calls itself recurivly. name the date data something else like `_date`

Comment: Do you mean in the initialization of the object or within the property and setter ?

Comment: Whenever you access object.date the function `def date(self)` is called. So when you access self.date inside that... `date(self)` is called. You must somehow distinguish between the getter and the data it gets. This is often done by naming the actual data `_data` so that when you return `self._data` it does *not* call `date(self)`.

Comment: Thanks. Now that you pointed that out is pretty obvious, but I couldn't find this myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object has a namespace (actually a `dict`) that keeps its members - regardless whether those are attribute, functions/methods or other things.

In your case, you are trying to use the name `date` both for the *method* and the *primitive*. This causes a collision, so either method or primitive is known under the name `date`.

Now, if `Debit.date` were a regular method, setting `self.date = date` in `__init__` would just overwrite the method with the value. Since `Debit.date` is a property, it uses custom behavior for setting the value - `self.date = date` will not replace the property, but call its setter `Debit.date.setter`.

The recursion arises because the setter attempts to write to `self.date` - which is again the property, and thus tries to use `Debit.date.setter` as well.

```
@date.setter  # makes the method available as `Debit.date`
def date(self, d):
  if len(d) == 0: 
    raise Exception("Date cannot be empty")
  self.date = d  # sets `Debit.date`, i.e. calls `Debit.date.setter(self, d)`
```

As pointed out in the comments to your question, the common approach to your case is to name the *property* `date` and the *attribute* `_date`. This avoids the name collision, but makes it clear that the two belong together.

```
class Debit(object):
  currency = "SEK"

  def __init__(self,date,tag,ammount):
    self.date = date  # use of self.date calls the setter to set self._date with input checking
    self.tag = tag
    self.ammount = ammount 

  @property
  def date(self):  # property getter
    return self._date  # provide attribute

  @date.setter
  def date(self, d):  # property setter
    if len(d) == 0: 
      raise Exception("Date cannot be empty")
    self._date = d  # set attribute
```